# How to process any request of the type example.com/request?

Tags: java, friendly-url

Suppose I own say add-one.com and if I receive add-one.com/23 I want to capture '23' and then display 24 to the user (for example http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overflow or any other word) instead of throwing a 404 error. How could I do this? I do not want to do anything like add-one.com/process.php?number=23.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using Servlets mostly because I know Java and I was planning to use google app engine. But I wanted to know about this so I can decided on which place to host..

Comment: The term used to describe what you want is "pretty urls". I'm not familiar with java, but could this be relevant? http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/1/13/pretty-urls-rails-style-with-webwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the request path. Take a look at the following examples on [THIS](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetReqUrl.html) page. It should help you get started.

For more complex projects, you should also get familiar with the basics of [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer). You can then start using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), a framework for building RESTful web services in Java.